# SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sys_contex..." - rest of line ignored

Tags: oracle

I Googled how to get the username of the current user and was told to use:

```
SQL> sys_context('userenv', 'session_user')
```

But when I type that command in, I get the error:

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sys_contex..." - rest of line ignored

What am I missing? The Oracle version is `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production`

Comment: `sys_context` is a function, you should use proper syntax to invoke it, either as part of a `select` statement or as an assignment in a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dual table part of select

```
SQL> SELECT sys_context('userenv', 'session_user') FROM dual;
```

Documentation:

[SYS_CONTEXT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086)